# Find a number that is between two values and return field corresponding to lower value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Another newbie question - I appreciate how everyone is so helpful here and I will return the favor for others. Here's what I am dealing with:

I have a table *tblAssignment* - this is just a sample of a bigger table, but I want it to be simple so I can convey it to you properly and then understand the logic behind any forthcoming answers:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| Lesson  | SkillNeeded |  EmployeeAssigned |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| Math    |           0 |  Mike             |
| Math    |           2 | Jason             |
| Math    |           5 | Derek             |
| Math    |           9 | John              |
| Math    |          13 | Brian             |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
```

So, I would have a desired skill number, and for this example, let's use the number 4. I need to have Access lookup that value in the table (under the *SkillNeeded* field) and I'd want it to suggest one name under the *EmployeeAssigned* field. With a 4, that number falls between Derek and Jason, who have a 2 and a 5, respectively. What I'd like returned is the the name that is associated with the lowest *SkillNeeded* number of which my number is between; so, in this example, it would be Jason.

Had my number been 8, the query would return Derek, because 8 would be between 5 and 9 and it would take the name associated with the lower *SkillNeeded* number of the two, which would be 5 and Derek.

I hope that made sense. Again, any and all help will be truly appreciated - thank you in advance!

-Josh

Comment: Nothing is wrong with a newbie question, but the general idea on Stack Overflow is that you try to discover the answer yourself (by searching for similar questions) and even test your own solution.  If you still need assistance, you should post what you have tried along with the requirements.

Comment: I think the best explanation you can provide in this case is: Sample data, conditions, and desired outputs. I don't see any desired outputs here

Comment: Thank you, C Perkins - I will follow that advice. And thanks to everyone who has helped!

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your description that you want to return an employee name with a maximum value of `skillNeeded` that is lower than input value. I will use input value 4 in my examples.

You may use `NOT EXISTS`

```
  SELECT * FROM tblAssignment t1
  WHERE t1.SkillNeeded < 4 AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tblAssignment t2
    WHERE t2.SkillNeeded < 4 AND t2.SkillNeeded > t1.SkillNeeded)
```

or `MAX`

```
 SELECT * FROM tblAssignment
 WHERE SkillNeeded = (SELECT MAX(SkillNeeded) FROM tblAssignment WHERE SkillNeeded < 4)
```

Comment: I presume the query should return the exact match if it exists, but neither of these queries do that.

Comment: @CPerkins Jason should be returned for number 4. That what the queries do.

Comment: @JoshC  Glad that you've figured it out.  If it is very helpful, then please upvote and/or select this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
Select TOP 1* from tblAssignment
   group by SkillNeeded 
            having SkillNeeded <= 4
                  order by desc;
```

Hope it helps!