# How to use sub query to list from a count statement?

Tags: sql, count, subquery, sql-server-2014, exists

We have some employees in TOTEMP table who has duplicate CIVILID and now i want to find their names matching from EMP table

I tried the following queries

```
SELECT P.FIRSTNAME,ID
FROM EMP p
where  exists (SELECT CIVILID, COUNT (CIVILID)
               FROM TOTEMP AS D
               group by CIVILID
               HAVING (COUNT (CIVILID) >1) )
```

> Selects all the records from the EMP table

2 ) I tried  an IN statement

```
SELECT P.FIRSTNAME,p.ID
FROM EMP p ,UDFEMP  k
where  p.ID in (SELECT CIVILID ,COUNT (CIVILID)
                FROM TOTEMP AS D
                group by CIVILID
                HAVING (COUNT (CIVILID) >1) )
```

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Regards

[image]

Comment: The EXISTS query needs a correlated subquery. The IN query needs a sub-select with only one column, CIVILID.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data or create a sqlfiddle with defined schema? That'll be really helpful and makes easy to solve the issue.

Comment: @Harshil , Updated the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.FIRSTNAME,p.ID,d.CIVILID
    FROM EMP p inner join TOTEMP d
    on p.id = d.id
    where  d.CIVILID in (select CIVILID from TOTEMP
                        group by CIVILID having count(ID)>1 );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The statement lists only one single record  multiple times

Comment: Edited the query. Check it out.

Comment: This time It returns the first record from the emp table

Comment: Please add schema in the question with sample data.

Comment: I dont know how to share it ,

Comment: Go through this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414081/find-a-number-that-is-between-two-values-and-return-field-corresponding-to-lower/46414899#46414899                                                                                 Create a table like in this question with your columns and data, than select whole table and put it inside code {}.

Comment: please try the edited query and see whether it works as i didn't test it.

Comment: this query is returning the result. seems fine

Comment: what did really happend, i dont see any difference from the query i tried from  above

Comment: I also want to select Civil id  with name and id . can u update the query

Comment: In your query, You're trying to compare id with civilid that's being repeated.That was causing the problem. What I did here is that, first select the repeated CIVILIDs (2nd subquery), match IDs with repeated CIVILID in TOTEMP table(1st subquery) and then compare this IDs with Ids of Emp table.

Comment: I modified it accordingly. Hope it works. Please try it out.

Comment: yeah.. now its returning with civilid

Comment: Can we do it with other than  join statement,  ?

Comment: Yes, we may do it without join. But it'll require multiple subqueries which will be ugly both lookwise and performance wise. Thank you for the +1 though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515705/how-to-make-your-server-as-linked-server-for-selected-views

Comment: Maybe you can help me with the above question  .  :)

Comment: Sorry...not aware about the Linked Server thing..I wish I can help you in the future with another queries.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done both with the `exists` and the `in` operators, but both your queries have issues.

The `exists` variant is missing a relation between `p` and `d`:

```
SELECT p.firstname, p.id
FROM   emp p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT   *
               FROM     totemp d
               WHERE    p.id = d.civilid -- Here!
               GROUP BY civilid
               HAVING   COUNT(civilid) > 1)
```

The `in` variant needs to just select the `id` in the inner query, not multiple columns (and doesn't need to cross join with `udfemp`):

```
SELECT p.firstname, p.id
FROM   emp p
where  p.id in (SELECT   civilid
                FROM     totemp
                GROUP BY civilid
                HAVING   COUNT(civilid) > 1)
```

Comment: The exists returned an error  , The conversion of the nvarchar value '260110101612' overflowed an int column.

Comment: The  in statement only returns one record  from the emp table

Comment: are `p.id` and `d.civilid` different datatypes?

Comment: Yes  , civilid is nvarchar .

Comment: I do have ID colum matching both tables