# How to make your Server as Linked Server for selected views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, oledbconnection, openquery

We have a SQL Server 2012 instance which is the database for our security system. Now we have a scenario where we want to allow another team our SQL Server to select certain records, ie we created four views for them for their requirements.

But, we don't want to provide or list all our tables to them but only allow these four views to see and query in our system. As I go through many documents it's clear that we can do it through making our SQL Server as a linked server.

What's the best way to do it through a linked server?

Answer (score 1):

Are the views in a specific schema?
Try to grant the users access to that schema, so that they can only read and see meta from it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration

Comment: At Present we have only one schema and all the views and tables are on same schema

Comment: Schemas are the most natural way to segment access.

Comment: so we need to create a seperate schema and put the views there .

Comment: Yes, and make sure they only have access to that schema. That is that is the right thing to do, in order for you to restrict select rights on the views. I think it will also restrict the meta information, but you will see.

Comment: Sure.what about the linked server part. is it needed in this case

Answer (score 1):

> we don't want to provide or list all our tables to them but only
>   allow these four views to see and query in our system.

You don't need linked server to accomplish this.

All you need is to grant `SELECT` permission on these 4 views.

When you create a user in a database and don't grant any permission to it, it does not see any user table/view at all. And it will be able to see and query only those objects on which you'll grant the permissions

Comment: So, in which case linked server is implemented ?

Comment: Linked server is implemented when you have 2 servers and want to elaborate data from both of them. i.e. you need to write queries like select * from server2.RemoteDB.dbo.myRemoteTable join dbo.myLocalTable